# I'm using Java Spring framework to map the date data from my data and my pathvariable won't get me access to any data

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm using the Java Spring framework to map data from a portion of my data and my @pathvariable won't get me access to any data. all I'm getting in the console is *

```
Trying 127.0.0.1:4001...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4001 (#0)
> GET /traveladventures/bydate/2017 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4001
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2022 17:19:19 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

my current code looks like such

```
@GetMapping("/bydate/{date}")
  public List<Adventure> getByDate(@PathVariable("date") String date){
    return this.adventureRepository.findByDate(date);
  }
```

I used this code to access my database

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:4001/traveladventures/bydate/2017
```

my interface

```
public interface AdventureRepository extends CrudRepository<Adventure, Integer> {
  public List<Adventure> findByDate(String date);
  date.substring(7,10);
}
```

an example of my SQL data looks like so

```
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (7, '05/16/2017', 'Uruguay', 'Salto', '', 43, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (8, '09/08/2016', 'Greece', 'Ãno LiÃ³sia', '', 94, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (9, '12/10/2020', 'Portugal', 'Azenhas do Mar', 'Lisboa', 5, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (11, '07/03/2020', 'China', 'Chishui', '', 9, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (10, '06/22/2019', 'Albania', 'Helmas', '', 7, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (13, '12/06/2016', 'France', 'AlenÃ§on', 'Basse-Normandie', 44, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (12, '01/06/2020', 'France', 'Quimper', 'Bretagne', 77, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (14, '04/01/2018', 'Japan', 'Ushiku', '', 13, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (15, '04/28/2021', 'Mexico', 'Fovissste', 'Chihuahua', 26, true);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (16, '09/21/2017', 'China', 'Xiaojin', '', 7, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (17, '08/31/2019', 'Syria', 'KhÄn ShaykhÅ«n', '', 4, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (18, '12/25/2020', 'Argentina', 'Zapala', '', 54, false);
INSERT INTO ADVENTURES (ID, DATE, COUNTRY, CITY, STATE, NUM_PHOTOS, BLOG_COMPLETED) VALUES (19, '04/25/2016', 'Philippines', 'Unidad', '', 72, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date in db is a date, ot at least a string formatted like a proper date, depending on how you declared the type, which is not clear from your question. With your get request - `/traveladventures/bydate/2017`, you are sending something that looks like a year. Considering dates in your db looks like this - `04/27/2019`, `2017` definitely won't match any of them.

**Edit:** The query generated from this method `List<Adventure> findByDate(String date);` will look for rows, whose date column is exact match of provided string. In your specific case it will return only rows, whose date is exact match for `2017`. The problem should be obvius now. In order to find anything, path variable should be in correct format - `<month>/<day>/<year>`, for example - `05/16/2017`. This will make correct url - `http://localhost:4001/traveladventures/bydate/05/16/2017`, which is another **problem** - you have url separatator as part of your path variable, you will probably get 404 response.

Solutions:

1. Use request parameter:

```
@GetMapping("/bydate/{date}")
public List<Adventure> getByDate(@PathVariable("date") String date){
  return this.adventureRepository.findByDate(date);
}
```

Url will look like this - `http://localhost:8080/traveladventures/bydate?date=05/16/2017`. Downside is you can only search for exact matches.

2. Change your entity: make date field of some date type. I would to stay away from `java.util.Date` and use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
@Column(name = "DATE")
private LocalDate date;
```

Then change your date column in table to be of datatype `DATE`. Like this you can do some more complex queries - for example get adventures in year 2017.

Comment: Do you need to see how the data is formatted? @ChaosFire

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein Editing the question with sql table declaration, or at the very least the date column declaration, and the `Adventure` entity would be useful.

Comment: my data mostly looks like so ` VALUES (7, '05/16/2017', 'Uruguay', 'Salto', '', 43, false);`

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein Can you share create table sql? The type of `DATE` column matters.

Comment: it iis created in java @Entity
@Table(name = "ADVENTURES")  in my public class Adventure { i have a method called   @Column(name = "DATE")
  private String date;

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein Check edit. And btw add adventure entity in question, it matters and should be part of it, not a comment.